# Drush and Composer installed but I'm getting errors

Tags: 8, drush, composer

Trying to use any drush command I get an error saying autoload.php won't load. It's in the vendor folder which is in the web root where I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be. It also has chmod +x permissions. If I put in php composer.phar I get the version and all that so yes it is there. If I run composer drupal-update (which composer manager would like for me to do) bash says composer: command not found. Is composer the only way to do this library thing in drupal 8? It seems a lot more problematic and less user friendly than just putting a library directory in the sites folder.

Comment: I think that a common use case is to install drush outside of the Drupal webroot (for instance in ~/ or globally).

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the error *-bash: composer: command not found*, that means Composer is not in the `PATH` Bash is using.

To use the *Composer Manager* module, you don't necessarily need Drush. I use it without Drush, but I run the following commands after I install the module.

```
cd <root directory of Drupal 8>
php modules/composer_manager/scripts/init.php
```

If all works fine, you will see the following output:

> Composer Manager has been successfully initialized.

In this way, the *Composer Manager* module adds a new command inside the composer.json file used by Drupal. In fact, after running those command, you will notice the following lines inside the composer.json file.

```
"drupal-rebuild": "Drupal\\composer_manager\\Composer\\Command::rebuild",
"drupal-update": "Drupal\\composer_manager\\Composer\\Command::update"
```

In the case you didn't execute those commands, or they failed for any reason, running `composer drupal-update` would return the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     Command "drupal-update" is not defined.

If you are downloading modules using Drush, just do as you normally do. The *Composer Manager* module will hook into Drush and do its task when a new module is downloaded.

Comment: well I actually already did that but ok I'll do it again. Yeah, same thing. it says composer manager has been successfully initialized but then when i run composer drupal-update it still says -bash: composer: command not found.

Comment: Are you sure composer is in the bash PATH?

Comment: Composer is definitely not installed. Refer to the instructions at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx.

Comment: After running `php modules/composer_manager/scripts/init.php` I had to run `composer update` before running `composer drupal-update`. If I skipped the second step, I got the Symfony error reported by kiamlaluno.